# curl sends empty json on content-type: application/json

Tags: bash, curl, content-type

I am sending cpu and memory usage on json format from Ubuntu to Node.js API using curl with POST method. However the json data is empty at Node.js server.

Bash script on Ubuntu

```
top -b -n 2 -d 0.5 > top.txt
cpu_i=$(grep Cpu top.txt | cut -d ',' -f 4 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
cpu=$(echo $cpu_i | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
echo $cpu

mem=$(grep "KiB Mem :" top.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2)
#echo $mem
mem_used=$(echo $mem | cut -d ',' -f 3 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
echo $mem_used

curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"cpu\":\"$cpu\", \"memory\":\"$mem_used\",\"device\":\"ubuntu\"}" http://192.168.10.10:4000/collector
```

Output at Node.js server

{}
Remote Address: ::ffff:192.168.10.5

Comment: idk how to read the raw request body with node, but just do that, that's where you'll find your json. in PHP it would be `$json=file_get_contents('php://input');$data=json_decode($json);`, idk what the Node equivalent is, but use that.

Comment: Can you show the `collector` function?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the httpverb is set to get by default. If you intend to post it, use `-X POST`. That will probably solve your problem, because the curl command is OK.

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"cpu\":\"$cpu\", \"memory\":\"$mem_used\",\"device\":\"ubuntu\"}" http://192.168.10.10:4000/collector
```

Comment: it's GET by default, but when using the `-d` argument, it's changed to POST by default, so that ain't it.

Comment: Nah, -d implies POST, there is no need to -X POST here

Comment: Ah.. The document does say that.